# Update image in service without downtime

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am running a service on Docker Swarm. This is what I did to deploy the service:

```
docker swarm init
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml MyApplication
```

Content of **docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        image: myimage:1.0
        ports:
            - "9000:80"
            - "9001:443"
        deploy:
            replicas: 3
            resources:
                limits:
                    cpus: "0.5"
                    memory: 256M
                restart_policy:
                    condition: on-failure
```

Let't say that I update the application and build a new image `myimage:2.0`. What is a proper way to deploy the new version of image to the service without the downtime?

Answer (score 8):

A way to achieve this is:

- provide a healthcheck. That way docker will know if your new deployment has succeeded.

  - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck
  - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck]
- control how docker will update your service with update_config

  - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#update_config
  - pay attention to `order` and `parallelism`, for example if you choose `order: stop-first` + `parallelism: 2` and your [replicas](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#replicas) are the same amount as `parallelism`, your app will stop completely when updating
- if your update doesn't succeed you probably want to rollback

  - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#rollback_config
- don't forget the [restart_policy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart_policy) too

I have some examples on that subject:

- [Docker Swarm Mode Replicated Example with Flask and Caddy](https://github.com/douglasmiranda/lab/tree/master/docker-swarm-replicated-example-caddy%2Bflask)
- https://github.com/douglasmiranda/lab/tree/master/caddy-healthcheck-of-caddy-itself

---

With this you can simply run `docker stack deploy...` again. If there was changes in the service, it will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the command `docker service update --image` but it will start a new container with a implicit scale 0/1.

The downtime depends of your application.